# Decryption using azure keyvault client old key version

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cryptography

I encrypt data using azure key vault client and cryptography client, I able to encrypt data, now I change the key version, and try to decrypt the data, but new version unable to decrypt data,

```
var keyName = "bcdfed";
var keyVaultUrl = "https://abcd.vault.azure.net";
var token = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var keyClient = new KeyClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), token);
var azureKey = await keyClient.GetKeyAsync(keyName);
var cryptographyClient = keyClient
    .GetCryptographyClient(azureKey.Value.Name, azureKey.Value.Properties.Version);
var inputValue = "input some value"; 
byte[] input = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputValue);

var encryptionResult = await cryptographyClient
    .EncryptAsync(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, input);
var encryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptionResult.Ciphertext);
byte[] encryptedResultByte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString); 
await cryptographyClient
    .DecryptAsync(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, encryptedResultByte);
```

I try to decrypt data using new version

Answer (score 0):

1. *Create a key vault in azure.*

[image]

2. *Create a key using key policies mentioned below.*

[image]

*Check the* [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-portal) *for creating keys in azure.*

*use the `key identifier` and `key name` in the code.*

[image]

```
             var keyVaultKeyIdentifier = new KeyVaultKeyIdentifier(new Uri("KeyIdnetifier"));               var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
  
              var keyClient = new KeyClient(keyVaultKeyIdentifier.VaultUri, credential);
  
              var keyVaultKey = keyClient.GetKey(keyVaultKeyIdentifier.Name).Value;
  
              
              var cryptographyClient = keyClient.GetCryptographyClient(keyVaultKey.Name, keyVaultKey.Properties.Version);
  
              byte[] plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Some plaintext");
  
              EncryptResult encryptResult = cryptographyClient.Encrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, plaintext);
  
              DecryptResult decryptResult = cryptographyClient.Decrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, encryptResult.Ciphertext);
  
              Console.WriteLine("Encrypt Result: " + Convert.ToBase64String(encryptResult.Ciphertext));
              Console.WriteLine();
              Console.WriteLine("Decrypt Result: " + Encoding.Default.GetString(decryptResult.Plaintext));
```

[image]

*Output:*
[image]

**Update**

*Yes, we have used the new version and able to decrypt.*

[image]

*please find the below screenshot from the code.*

[image]

Comment: No Issue while encryption and decrypt from same key version, if you create new version of key and decrypt already encrypt data, at that time it throw error.

Comment: Please find the update in the answer, *And check the keyvault or keypolicies* [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-portal) *for creating keys in azure.*

Comment: I follow the same approach whatever you completed, 
Follow below step, 
1. Encrypt test using xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx key version and save somewhere encrypted test.
2. Update Key version in keyvault 
3. then directly decrypt already encrypted text using new version : yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Comment: I am able to get the same decryption value even after changing the versions.